# C# wpf привязка данных

Tags: c#, wpf

Появилась нужда привязать progressbar, label к данным с внешнего файла xml. Можно это сделать средствами xaml? Если да, то какими. У данный момент это реализовано дополнительным классом, который считывает файл и выступает в роли модели.

Comment: И что вас не устраивает? Зачем вам привязываться напрямую к файлу?

Comment: Меня всё устраивает, вопрос стал в том, что можно ли так сделать, и будет ли лучше